# ResultSet is not null but giving a null pointer exception

Tags: java, jdbc

i have 16 to 17 record in DB
BUT when i want to retrive data.... on the run time i received null pointer exceptiion
(sorry for bad english)

```
 sql="SELECT * FROM CUSTOMER ORDER BY date DESC"; //my query
stmt=con.prepareStatement(sql);   //preparedStatement
System.out.println("2");    //checking output (where is exception)
rs=stmt.executeQuery();    //resultsetGlobal declare
System.out.println("3");    //checking outpur
i=0;    //for show record number
System.out.println(i);     //checking output
while(rs.next()){     //here i get the exception any one tell me why exception??
}
```

Comment: Before the while put this snipet: `if ( rs == null ){ System.out.println("It is null!"); }` A NullPointerException only occurs when you are making an access to a null object

Comment: Where is rs defined? That could be null. What does rs.hasNext() return?

Comment: Maybe there is an error while executing the query? I think there should be a method of rs to check if the last execution gave errors.

Comment: @MightyPork Even in this case resultset would not be null.

Comment: Probably you can add some more code to make it clear. What is happening INSIDE the while loop?

Comment: @MightyPork `executeQuery()` never returns `null`.

Comment: i tried this code(between the loop and rs=stmt.executeQuery) it is returning id but still getting exception 
rs=stmt.executeQuery();
            rs.next();
            String ids=rs.getString("ID");
            System.out.println(ids);
            System.out.println("yahn tak cahl gya hy");
            while(rs.next()){
String id=rs.getString("Id");
System.out.println(id);
}

Comment: @AndrewStubbs there is no method hasNext().

Comment: @Yasin 
while(rs.next()){
 String id = rs.getString("ID");
        String date = rs.getString("Date");
        System.out.println(id+"   "+date);
}

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get NPE where you are pointing. `while(rs.next())` this line will throw NPE if and only if the variable `rs` is null. And the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#executeQuery(java.lang.String)) says:

> executeQuery() returns a ResultSet object that contains the data
>   produced by the given query; never null`

Hence, after `rs=stmt.executeQuery();` the variable `rs` cannot be null. The source of the NPE could be somewhere else in the code but not the condition in `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

If this is the real code you must be setting 'rs' to null *later,* inside the 'while' loop.

Comment: i am not setting rs=null inside the loop
but if i am setting it null atleast it should must return 1 record from db....
while(rs.next()){ String id = rs.getString("ID"); String date = rs.getString("Date"); System.out.println(id+" "+date); }